# Why do suggested edits get a special notification?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

For users with enough rep, there is a notification for suggested edits pending approval to the left of the chat link.

[image]

With six different review queues (close, votes, late answers, suggested edits, low quality posts, first posts, and reopen votes), what makes suggested edits special enough to have its own alert? Since I've topped out my badge progress for suggested edits, and the close votes queue is current at 54.5k, I've been focusing on the close votes queue and don't need to be reminded of the suggested edits more than I do any other queue.

Comment: This alert existed before the new queues, when there was only the one queue. That's why it's special

Comment: The queue for the suggested edits is limited; the number of suggested edits is shown because suggested edits should be handled as quicker as possible.

Comment: Reviews were also pretty hard to come by before the new system as well, and they were *required* for suggested edits, unlike new/closed/close voted/etc posts, which don't require urgent action to...*exist*, which suggested edits do

Answer (score 7):

As part of being a 10K+ user, you get access to tools that are very closely related to the tools that a diamond moderator sees.

Flags and suggested edits, while different, both involve pending actions that are not completed until someone with some level of authority, like a 2k+ user or a 10K+ user, can approve them.

To elaborate, these edits are held back visually from all other users until approved, so the quicker they're reviewed, the faster the edits are applied.

The other review queues, while important, involve actions that suppress posts rather than expose them. For instance, first posts and late answers, if not reviewed, are still visible to all users. These posts need reviews only to receive more upvotes or to receive special attention if they're poor quality, like editing or deletion.

For close votes and delete votes, the goal is also to suppress or remove poor quality content. There's not as big of a rush here.  Again, with edits, the goal is to expose content.

Keep in mind that users with less than 10K+ rep can still approve suggested edits, but they don't see the moderation tools that you do, and they don't see the bat signals. While these things may be legacy tools that existed before the new review tools were released, the old review queues also weren't highlighted via the bat signal, only suggested edits and flags.

Lastly, an important point raised by kiamlaluno is that the suggested edit queue is finite. If people aren't approving edits and they max out the queue, then no more suggested edits can be made.

Comment: +1 for good points raised here, I would also add what kiamlaluno [said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152057/why-do-suggested-edits-get-a-special-notification#comment436758_152057) - the queue of suggested edits is limited, while the others can reach thousands upon thousands.